# What happens if, after battle, board is still full?

Tags: neuroshima-hex

What happens, if the board is full and after battle (resulting from the full board) it stays that way?

Moreover, what happens if - in such situation - opponent has the possibility to perform action despite full board? For example sniper, small bomb, large bomb, ability to replace opponent or self units with new ones etc.

Comment: Did it happen to you or is this purely theoretical question?

Comment: It did :) I was playing Steel Police and managed to get rid of most of opponent's units, leaving only two (including the base), which were netted, but not attacked. As an effect, after the battle, opponent's base received damage, my didn't and no units or modules were damaged or destroyed.

Comment: Theoretically one might run battle one after another and either pronounce victory of one of players or a draw (if they have same number of HPs for bases and either no damage is being dealt during battle or damage to both bases is equal). However, situation is getting more interesting when armies, which are battling, can put their new units in place of their or opponent's ones already placed on the board. Also, tere are small and big bombs and snipers.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with that. If board is still full after one battle, I'd immediately run another, and so on, untill one player wins/situation changes. Or if board state stays the same, then it's a draw. I don't know official rulings on this occasion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You have another Battle immediately.**

On page 5 of the [game rules](http://portalgames.pl/new_en/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/EN_Neuroshima_Hex_3_0_rulebook.pdf):

> If at any time during the game the board is filled up and no single space is left to place a tile on, a Battle commences (see BATTLES section below).

Even if the Battle results in a stalemate, the game will eventually end. As soon as the Battle ends, so does the active player's turn:

> The player who starts a Battle (by playing Battle tile or filling up the board) finishes his turn, regardless of the number of tiles he has left. As soon as the Battle commences, no other tiles can be used or even discarded.

As such, the next player takes their turn, drawing and discarding. Because the board is full, a battle happens immediately (before they can play tiles or use other abilities). Eventually, a player will draw their last tile. An automatic battle happens on that turn due to the board being full, then again on the opponent's turn, and then the final battle happens.

If both HQs have the same points left, each player takes an extra turn (a.k.a. two more battles), and then there's an additional final battle. If there's still no winner, it's a draw.

Comment: "Immediately" implies nothing happens in between, but you're saying the turn passes and the next player draws  and discards. Perhaps "Play passes to the next player, resulting in another Battle" would be a more accurate summary?

Comment: Also, while I find your answer compelling, it seems to me like it would be better from a design perspective to allow Instant Action tiles to be used if drawn in the scenario, and I'd be interested to hear if the game dev wanted to clarify. :)

Comment: @AndrewVandever, yes, I interpreted it as the draw structure of a turn is forced because the rule for immediate battling was contained in the section for playing tiles. It could be argued that it happens infinitely, but I thought this made more sense as it forces the game end, and there's no other distinction between the two ways. Instant speed actions might be reasonable to allow.